# Proxmox on Debian 11 (5.15) share gpu between host and vm's

Tags: debian, gpu, nvidia

I have Proxmox 7 running on Debian 11 with proxmox kernel 5.15. In the server there are 2 Nvidia GTX cards (1060 and 1050). I managed to install vgpu driver NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-460.32.04-vgpu-kvm.run (with patch), unlock vgpu and create profiles.

My question is - is there any way to somehow assign 1 profile to host OS? nouveau is blacklisted and KDE or Cinnamon are not working with kvm grid nvidia driver.

I just want a GUI not only in VMs, but on this server as well. Is it possible?

Best regards, KB

Answer (score 0):

if you are using debian 10 or any other linux distros and trying to install vgpu driver, try installing debian 11 and then try to install the driver it always works for me.
if the driver asked for the kernel-headers just install it, but i didnt succeed in debian 10.
if anyone was able to install it in debian 10 please let me know.